# How to compare std::string to "" properly?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to compare an std::string to `""` on this way:

```
std::string str = "ooo";
bool a = str.compare("") == 0; // marked line
```

On the marked line, I'm getting an exception on the `compare` function.

How may I deal with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tell us the exception, and ... are you sure that's the line? If you run the code you've shown us (assuming its edited from the original) does it still throw an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
bool a = str.empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for compare, you can (and should) directly write

```
bool a = str == "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Member function compare does not throw an exception. So this code

```
std::string str = "ooo";
bool a = str.compare("") == 0;
```

is valid though looks weird.

You could write simply

```
bool a = str.empty();
```

or

```
bool a = str == "";
```

I think that the reason of the exception is somewhere else.

An exception can occur if for example you use something as

```
bool a = str.compare( 0 ) == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `std::string::size` or `std::string::length` instead. The two methods are synonymous.

```
bool a = !str.size(); /*note the implicit cast to bool*/
```

`size` is preferred as it's more symmetric with other container objects.

(You could also use `str.empty()` but, personally, I dislike it since the method name sounds too much like it's going to modify the string. I wouldn't want to be fooled during a 4am debugging session).

Comment: For string, the idiomatic way is probably `str == ""`; for all other containers, it is `container.empty()`.  (And no, I don't like the name either; it should be `is_empty()`.)  What is definitely confusing is `!str.size()`: `str.size()` doesn't return a `bool` to begin with, so using `!` on it involves a confusing implicit conversion.